# Can I call a Map Method with innerclass in another class?

Tags: apex

```
public with sharing class classA{
           public  map<string,map<string,innerclass>> methodA(){
             map<string,map<string,innerclass>> fieldA = new map<string,map<string,innerclass>>();
             //some code here
             map<string,innerclass> fieldB = new map<string,innerclass>();
             fieldB.put('str',innerclassval);
             fieldA.put('str1',fieldB);
             return fieldA;
           }
```

In fieldA value will be something like this ------- str1={str={link1,link2}}

My Second Class is

```
public class ClassB{
   public ClassB(){
    classA ca = new classA();
    map<string,map<string,innerclass>> inmap = ca.methodA(); // getting error as Invalid type innerclass

   }
}
```

Now how can I call this class in another class where I need link1,link2 Values .Help!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First class:

```
public class ClassA{
    public ClassA(){
    }

    public Map<String,Map<String,InnerClass>> methodA(){
        Map<string,map<String,InnerClass>> fieldA = new Map<String,Map<String,InnerClass>>();
        //some code here
        Map<String,InnerClass> fieldB = new Map<String,InnerClass>();
        fieldB.put('str',innerclassval);
        fieldA.put('str1',fieldB);
        return fieldA;
    }

    public class InnerClass{
        public InnerClass(){

        }
    }
}
```

Reference class:

```
public class ClassB{
    public ClassB(){
    }
    public void fakeMethod(){
        ClassA classAInstance = new ClassA();
        Map<String, Map<String, ClassA.InnerClass>> fullMapInstance = classAInstance.methodA();
    }
}
```

You should check out the [Apex documentation on defining classes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_defining.htm). Here is a good example on [Extending Apex Classes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_classes_example.htm). In fact, I would recommend just reading up on all the [documentation Salesforce provides on Classes, Objects, and Interfaces](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_classes.htm).

Comment: @EagerinSf I don't know what you are trying to do now to be honest. Can you update your original question with the code you are getting this error on please? I would like to help you, but I am not understanding your problem now I think.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just create a new reference of cassA in classB and then call that method like this:

```
public with sharing class classA{
    public  map<string,map<string,innerclass>> methodA(String param1){
        map<string,map<string,innerclass>> fieldA = new map<string,map<string,innerclass>>();
        //some code here
        map<string,innerclass> fieldB = new map<string,innerclass>();
        fieldB.put('str',innerclassval);

        if(param1 == null)
            String s = ... // generating the String because the param1 is unll
            param1 = s;
        }

        fieldA.put(param1,fieldB);
        return fieldA;
    }
}

public with sharing class classB{
    public classB(){
        String s = {link1,link2};
        classA c1 = new classA();
        map<string,map<string,innerclass>> m = c1.methodA(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your second class to your original post and show how you are referencing this map? I am a bit confused as to what you are trying to do now.

Comment: @JesseAltman just updated my example

Comment: My original comment was towards a comment @EagerinSf put on your question but he apparently deleted it. I understood what you were referencing. Thanks for taking the time to help him out though! Upvoted!